# Python bs4 lxml parsing slow

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing

while parsing with bs4,lxml and looping trough my files with ThreadPoolExecutor threading I am experiencing really slow results. I have searched the whole internet for faster alternatives on this one. The parsing of about 2000 cached files (1.2mb each) takes about 15 minutes (max_workes=500) on ThreadPoolExecutor. I even tried parsing on Amazon AWS with 64 vCPU but the speed remains about the same.

I want to parse about 100k files which will takes hours of parsing. Why isn't the parsing not efficiently speeding up while multiprocessing? One file takes about 2seconds. Why is the speed of 10 files with (max_workes=10) not equaling 2 seconds as well since the threads are concurrent? Ok maybe 3 seconds would be fine. But it takes ages the more files there are, the more workers I assign to the threads. It get's to the point of about ~ 25 seconds per file instead of 2 seconds when running a sinlge file/thread. Why?

What can I do to get the desired 2-3 seconds per file while multiprocessing?

If not possible, any faster solutions?

My approch for the parsing is the following:

```
with open('cache/'+filename, 'rb') as f:
        s = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'lxml')
        s.whatever()
```

Any faster way to scrape my cached files?

// the multiprocessor:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed


future_list = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=500) as executor:
    for filename in os.listdir("cache/"):
        if filename.endswith(".html"):
            fNametoString = str(filename).replace('.html','')
            x = fNametoString.split("_")
            EAN = x[0]
            SKU = x[1]
            future = executor.submit(parser,filename,EAN,SKU)
            future_list.append(future)
        else:
            pass
for f in as_completed(future_list):
        pass
```

Comment: Can you post the whole example code how are you using the `multiprocessing` now?

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes, I added it to the question

Comment: What is `parser` that you're submitting to executor?

Comment: @AndrejKesely It is the class where bs4 get's initiated and is processing the cached files

Comment: Try to use `multiprocessing.Pool` and `.imap_unordered()`. Submit only a filename you want to parse. Each worker should open the file, parse it and return a result.

Comment: But isn't this exactly what I am doing? I am passing each worker a filename and each worker should open the file, parse it and return a result? 

Do you have an example code for the specific scenario? @AndrejKesely

Comment: I've posted some proof of concept. You can try it and see if it speeds up the processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing import Pool


def worker(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f_in:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), "html.parser")

    # do some processing here
    return soup.h1.text.strip()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    filenames = ["page1.html", "page2.html", ...] # you can use glob module or populate the filenames list other way

    with Pool(4) as pool:  # 4 is number of processes
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(worker, filenames):
            print(result)
```